# Receive a broadcast intent when the packet data of the device is enabled

Tags: android, android-intent

I am writing an Android application in which the application should start setup for the first time when the packet data for the device is enabled (not wifi data only packet data) and the device latched to the data.

I have registered the receiver with the action `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` and for getting the required info I have used the following code snippet:

```
NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(
    ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
info.isConnected();
```

But I am getting the "**info**" as null. I have also searched for the parcelable `ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_EXTRA_INFO` that also got as null.

Kindly please help me in solving the issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example class to do this for you. Have one in your Activity, remember to start/stop it when Activity pauses/resumes, and call its `isConnected()` from anywhere in the Activity:

```
public class ConnectivityListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager;
    private volatile boolean mConnected;

    public boolean isConnected() {
        return mConnected;
    }

    public ConnectivityListener(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    }

    public void startListening(){
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
        mContext.registerReceiver(this,filter);
    }

    public void stopListening(){
        mContext.unregisterReceiver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NetworkInfo n = mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if(n != null){
            mConnected = n.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE && n.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        }else {
            mConnected = false;
        }
    }
}
```